# Resize listview margin animation lagging

Tags: android, listview, animation

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:cube_ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background">

    <!-- Header -->
    <customheader
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/header_height" />

    <!-- List-->
    <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"  />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And the animation:

```
int headerHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);

Animation anim = new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mHeader.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, (int) (-headerHeight  * interpolatedTime), 0, 0);
        mHeader.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
};
anim.setDuration(400);
mHeader.startAnimation(anim);
```

The animation is working and the header's animation is smooth but the ListView (StickyHeader) is very laggy :(  What is the solution? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
...
getView().setY((int) (-headerHeight  * interpolatedTime);
...
```

It works like a charm :)